# JSF ViewState fix IE responseXML

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jsf-2, xmlhttprequest, omnifaces

I have a problem that I used ViewState fix in JSF library from OmniFaces: [fixviewstate.js](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/javax.faces.resource/fixviewstate.unminified.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces&v=2.2). The problem is that we encountered weird behaviour of IE in our application, where after second AJAX request to the same page, data.responseXML = {}. Strange thing is that responseText is properly set. And in that case viewState value = '-'. Such value is then submitted to the server and JSF throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

This only happens in IE, but does not when developer tools are enabled. I thought that this might be related to IE AJAX caching problem, but:

- those are posts requests
- content-type is properly set to text/xml
- Cache-Control: no-cache header is set

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it working. It occurred that although response looks like this:

```
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-1644237968690251221:-7863929220167075939]]>
```

update.firstChild.nodeValue on IE returns only part of the text - sometimes only "-", sometimes "-1644237968690251221". It all depends how browser will slice the text into text nodes. And according to the spec it can do it in any way.
So we just need to call update.textContent.

Comment: Nice find! I will investigate browser compatibility and then apply the fix in OmniFaces itself. Edit: it appears [IE6-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) doesn't like this and `innerText` should be used instead. Can you confirm if `return updates[i].textContent || updates[i].innerText;` works fine for you across IE (emulated) versions?

Comment: Well, updates[i].textContent || updates[i].text seem to work. But I just went with jQuery version $(updates[i]).text().